# go + SDL + OpenGL + MacOS example = I get INVALID_OPERATION after DrawArrays()

Tags: macos, go, opengl, sdl

SDL version: 2.0.12
OpenGL version: 3.3 INTEL-10.4.14
*I had to force the OpenGL version to 3.3 by requesting core profile, the default version I would get otherwise is 1.2*

Following this video tutorial http://youtu.be/yxAPS2eyKmA *Games with Go*, I tried the OpenGL sample code, and it just shows a black window.
It's supposed to render an orange triangle.

I'm getting `INVALID_OPERATION` after the second-to-last statement `gl.DrawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3)`

https://gist.github.com/ErnestoBorio/87b09bf3cc496657a83637fd4876e943

```golang
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "strings"

        "github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.3-core/gl"
        "github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/sdl"
    )

    func DontPanic(err error) {
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    var GLversion = [...]int {3, 3}

    func main() {
        DontPanic(
            sdl.Init(sdl.INIT_EVERYTHING))
        defer sdl.Quit()

        DontPanic(
            sdl.GLSetAttribute(sdl.GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, sdl.GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE))
        DontPanic(
            sdl.GLSetAttribute(sdl.GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, GLversion[0]))
        DontPanic(
            sdl.GLSetAttribute(sdl.GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, GLversion[1]))

        window, err := sdl.CreateWindow("OpenGL", 200, 200, 1280, 720, sdl.WINDOW_OPENGL)
        DontPanic(err)

        window.GLCreateContext()
        defer window.Destroy()

        GLversionStr := fmt.Sprintf("%d%d0", GLversion[0], GLversion[1])

        gl.Init()
        version := gl.GoStr(gl.GetString(gl.VERSION))
        fmt.Println("OpenGL Version", version)

        vertexShaderSrc :=
            "#version "+ GLversionStr +" core \n"+
            "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;"+
            "void main() {"+
                "gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);"+
            "}\x00"

        vertexShader := gl.CreateShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER)
        csource, free := gl.Strs(vertexShaderSrc)
        gl.ShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, csource, nil)
        free()
        gl.CompileShader(vertexShader)
        var status int32
        gl.GetShaderiv(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS, &status)
        if status == gl.FALSE {
            var logLength int32
            gl.GetShaderiv(vertexShader, gl.INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength)
            log := strings.Repeat("\x00", int(logLength+1))
            gl.GetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, logLength, nil, gl.Str(log))
            panic("Failed to compile vertex shader:\n" + log)
        }

        fragmentShaderSrc :=
            "#version "+ GLversionStr +" core \n"+
            "out vec4 FragColor;"+
            "void main() {"+
                "FragColor = vec4(1, 0.5, 0.2, 1);"+
            "}\x00"

        fragmentShader := gl.CreateShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        csource, free = gl.Strs(fragmentShaderSrc)
        gl.ShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, csource, nil)
        free()
        gl.CompileShader(fragmentShader)
        gl.GetShaderiv(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS, &status)
        if status == gl.FALSE {
            var logLength int32
            gl.GetShaderiv(fragmentShader, gl.INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength)
            log := strings.Repeat("\x00", int(logLength+1))
            gl.GetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, logLength, nil, gl.Str(log))
            panic("Failed to compile fragment shader:\n" + log)
        }

        shaderPrg := gl.CreateProgram()
        gl.AttachShader(shaderPrg, vertexShader)
        gl.AttachShader(shaderPrg, fragmentShader)
        gl.LinkProgram(shaderPrg)
        gl.GetProgramiv(shaderPrg, gl.LINK_STATUS, &status)
        if status == gl.FALSE {
            panic("Error in Linker, error logging not yet implemented.")
        }
        gl.DeleteShader(vertexShader)
        gl.DeleteShader(fragmentShader)

        vertices := []float32{
            -.5, -.5, 0,
            .5, -.5, 0,
            0,  .5, 0,
        }

        var vertexBuffer uint32
        gl.GenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer)
        gl.BindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer)
        var vertexArray uint32
        gl.GenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArray)
        gl.BindVertexArray(vertexArray)

        gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, len(vertices)*4, gl.Ptr(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
        gl.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 3*4, nil)
        gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        gl.BindVertexArray(0)

        EventPoll:
        for {
            for event := sdl.PollEvent(); event != nil; event = sdl.PollEvent() {
                switch event.(type) {
                    case *sdl.QuitEvent:
                        break EventPoll
                }
            }
            gl.ClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)
            gl.Clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
            gl.BindVertexArray(vertexArray)
            gl.DrawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3)
            window.GLSwap()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never calls `glUseProgram` which means you attempt to draw without a current program object, which is not valid in core profile OpenGL.

Comment: Oh right, the tutorial doesn't use Core, so that's why they may not use it. Yes that was it, thanks!

Comment: Well, even if the tutorial doesn't use core profile, it should activate the shaders. It is true that the fixed function pipeline in its default state will end up with the same vertex transforms, but the color defined in the FS wouldn't appear that way.